# How to setup 2D Colliders and Rigibody2D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new to C# and Unity so pls bear with me. How can I check if something is colliding with let's say a jump pad and the object that is colliding has a rigibody2D so I can manipulate the objects rigibody2d velocity.y? I looked thru the documentation but I still don't get it. I have in the Jump Pad  a rigibody2d Body type; Dynamic, Box Collider2D Is trigger; checked, and in my Box/Crate the same as Jump Pad only Box Collider2D Is trigger; not checked.
This works but it works only for one crate/box I'm looking for a way to check if any GameObject with rigibody2d collides and if so it should "jump/bounce" on the jump pad.

```css
    public class JumpPad : MonoBehaviour
    {
       private GameObject _gameObject;
        private Rigidbody2D _rigibody2d;
   
         void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collider)
        {
            _gameObject = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Crate");
           _rigibody2d = _gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
            _rigibody2d.velocity = new Vector2(0, 22f);
         }
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For cases like these you can use the `OnCollisionEnter` method.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    AudioSource audioSource;

    void Start()
    {
        audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        foreach (ContactPoint contact in collision.contacts)
        {
            Debug.DrawRay(contact.point, contact.normal, Color.white);
        }
        if (collision.relativeVelocity.magnitude > 2)
            audioSource.Play();
    }
}
```

There is ofcourse also `OnTriggerEnter` for colliders with `IsTrigger` set to `true`:

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerEnter.html

Check the docs carefully about the differences and which one is applicable to your case.

In your case I think you want something as follows:

```cs
   public class JumpPad : MonoBehaviour
    {
       private GameObject _gameObject;
        private Rigidbody2D _rigibody2d;
   
      void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
    {
        var colliderHasTag = col.gameObject.tag == "crate";

        if(!colliderHasTag)
            return;
 
        var rb = col.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(0, 22f);       
 
    }
```

The idea is that when a collision occurs, you check the object you're colliding with. Then if it has certain parameters (like the tag 'crate') you apply your action (like adding a bunch of force).

Comment: Thank you for the feedback I will look into it I really appreciate how fast the respond was, one more question is looking for tag resource-heavy I will have more than one crate/box.

Comment: That will be fine - worry about performance when it becomes and issue, first get some experience. Just refrain from using `Gameobject.Find(string name)` and instead use findbytags etc so you minimize search time if you have to.

Comment: I get an error operator "!" cannot be applied to operands of type " string" I tried to check if it's true if (colliderHasTag == "crate" ) it works but it works on all gameobjects not only tag " crate ".

Comment: @DenisGalla make sure the line is `var colliderHasTag = col.gameObject.tag == "crate";` not `var colliderHasTag = col.gameObject.tag = "crate";` (equals operator, not the assignment operator)

Comment: @DenisGalla I had made an error when posting this answer - never blatantly copy code from the internet ;) Make sure to mark he answer as accepted if this solves your question when you can, else let me know if still need to know something.